# mariaDB bulk update very slow

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mariadb

I need to update 290 000 lines from a csv file in my database.

I created a loop on each line to do an update, the quesry looks like this :

```
UPDATE lines_table
INNER JOIN account ON lines_table.account_id = account.id
SET account.is_updated = 1
WHERE account.is_updated = 1
AND lines_table.user_id=XXXXX
AND lines_table.code = 'YY';
AND account.compte 'ZZZZZZZ';
```

the php loop looks like this :

```
$conn = $this->em->getConnection();
while (([$key, $account, $user] = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== false) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

On my computer (wamp + symfony3 + SSD + mariaDB), it updates 85 lines per second.

When i execute this loop in my test environment (linux + symfony3 + 48 HDD 10k rpm, mariaDB), it updates only 4 lines per second.

Is there a config that could be different and make this loop slower ?

Comment: Instead of executing a query for every line, use transaction instead. It will save a lot of time

Comment: Prepare once, execute many. Or is there any reason that you need to reprepare the statement within loop?